# Javascript - How to remove texts in between brackets

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know a simple way to change:

`My name[1] is David Smith[ref.2] and my home is in Auburn[Geo-Ref3], AL.`

into

`My name is David Smith and my home is Auburn, AL.`

If I do

`string.replace(/\[.*\]/g, "")`

then I get

`My name, AL.`

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps `/\[[^\]]*\]/g`

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks, this works too. Could you please elaborate a little bit how it works? Thanks.

Comment: This should be read as `\[` `[^\]]*` `\]`. The block `[^\]]` is in turn read as `[^` `\]` `]` with the `[^` and `]` meaning "everything except", so overall that block is "everything except `]`".

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks. I understood. One question is that I think ```[^\[]``` should also work but it doesn't. I see that ```[^i]``` works.

Comment: `/\[[^\[]*\]/g` works for me, though the mechanism is a bit more tricky

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.*` will match greedily (as much as possible) by default. So the regex matched

```
My name[1] is David Smith[ref.2] and my home is in Auburn[Geo-Ref3], AL.
       ^----------------------------------------------------------^
```

You want to match reluctantly (as little as possible), which has syntax `.*?`. So use `string.replace(/\[.*?\]/g, "")`. This will match

```
My name[1] is David Smith[ref.2] and my home is in Auburn[Geo-Ref3], AL.
       ^-^               ^-----^                         ^--------^
```